# fetch corresponding codes saved in mulitple rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Below table, table_a contain ID, codes and corresponding values:

| Id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | 12 |
| 1 | code2 | 10 |
| 1 | code3 | 09 |
| 1 | code4 | 89 |
| 1 | code5 | 71 |
| 2 | code1 | 12 |
| 2 | code2 | 96 |
| 2 | code3 | 58 |
| 2 | code4 | 74 |

below table, table_b contain corresponding vat_number for the id.

| id | vat_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 58965 |
| 2 | 56974 |

I need to fetch only ID,vatnumber and code1 and code2.

final output should appear like below:

| ID | vat_number | code1 | code2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 58965 | 12 | 10 |
| 2 | 56974 | 12 | 96 |

currently I am fetching data using below query but I believe there must be a better way to fetch such information. I am using oracle 11g.

```
select b.id, b.vat_number, a.value,c.value
from table_a a, table_b b, table_a c
where a.id=b.id and b.id=c.id
and a.code='code1' and c.code='code2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is okay, but you should use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
select b.id, b.vat_number, a1.value, a2.value
from table_b b join
     table_a a1
     on a1.id = b.id and a1.code = 'code1' join
     table_a a2
     on a2.id = b.id and a2.code = 'code2';
```

You can also use conditional aggregation

```
select b.id, b.vat_number,
       max(case when a.code = 'code1' then a.value end),
       max(case when a.code = 'code2' then a.value end)
from table_b b join
     table_a a
     on a.id = b.id
where a.code in ('code1', 'code2')
group by b.id, b.vat_number;
```

You can run a test to see which is faster on your data.

Comment: Second query is much faster. However I don't understand why max is used here. I understand case clause but why max.. is it possible to explain? Thanks.

Comment: @sanjaysinghchauhan . . . There is only (presumably) one match so `max()` returns that value.  You need an aggregation function for the aggregation to work.  Note:  In most databases, I think the two-join solution would be faster, but Oracle does `group by` very well.